# ArcPy ConvertTimeZone() - how to conditionally use this function

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-pro, time-zone

I want to create a script that looks at a date field, sees the timezone, and then converts it to PST if it's in UTC (and leave it alone if it's already in PST).

I'm having issues with the "if" part of this statement.
How do I use ArcPy to "read" the date field and see what the timezone is?

Here's what I have so far:

```
 import arcpy

 #set project and map variables
 aprx = arcpy.mp.ArcGISProject('CURRENT')
 m = aprx.listMaps('*')[0]

 in_table = 'Daily Reports Test'
 input_time_field = 'DateTaken'
 input_time_zone = 'UTC'
 output_time_field = 'DatePST'
 output_time_zone = 'Pacific_Standard_Time'
 input_DST = 'INPUT_ADJUSTED_FOR_DST'
 output_DST = 'OUTPUT_ADJUSTED_FOR_DST'

 arcpy.management.ConvertTimeZone(in_table, input_time_field, input_time_zone, output_time_field, output_time_zone, input_DST, output_DST)
```

Answer (score -1):

This is the kind of question that ChatGPT would be good for. Straight out of ChatGPT:

To check the timezone of a date field and perform conditional operations based on it, you can utilize the datetime and pytz modules in Python. Here's an updated version of your script that includes the logic for checking the timezone and converting the date field to PST if it's in UTC:

```py
import arcpy
import pytz
from datetime import datetime

# Set project and map variables
aprx = arcpy.mp.ArcGISProject('CURRENT')
m = aprx.listMaps('*')[0]

in_table = 'Daily Reports Test'
input_time_field = 'DateTaken'
output_time_field = 'DatePST'

# Get the timezone for PST
pst = pytz.timezone('America/Los_Angeles')

# Iterate through the rows of the input table
with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(in_table, [input_time_field, output_time_field]) as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
        input_time = row[0]
        
        # Check if the input time is in UTC
        if input_time.tzinfo == pytz.UTC:
            # Convert the input time to PST
            output_time = input_time.astimezone(pst)
        else:
            # The input time is already in PST, no conversion needed
            output_time = input_time
        
        # Update the output time field with the converted time
        row[1] = output_time
        cursor.updateRow(row)
```

In this script, the `pytz` module is used to define the Pacific Standard Time (PST) timezone. The `datetime` module is used to compare the timezone of the input time with UTC.

The script then iterates through each row of the input table using an `UpdateCursor`. For each row, it checks the timezone of the input time. If it's in UTC, the script converts the time to PST using the `astimezone()` method. If the time is already in PST, no conversion is needed.

Finally, the output time field is updated with the converted time using `updateRow()`.

Make sure to update the `'America/Los_Angeles'` timezone value in the `pytz.timezone()` function to the appropriate timezone if you're not working with PST.

Note: This script assumes that the date field in the input table is stored as a `datetime` object. If it's stored as a string or another format, you may need to modify the script accordingly to parse the date and time correctly.

Comment: Hm...this copied everything over to the other column and kept the timezone the same. It's stored as a "Date" field, but I'm assuming I need to pass the info through Python's datetime.strptime() to create the datetime object the script is looking for?